# Como procurar uma palavra em 10 tabelas no MySQL

Tags: mysql, query

Estou a fazer um formulário para uma pesquisa, e ao procurar por algo, pretendo que retorne vários valores de varias tabelas que existem.

Como tal, gostaria de saber a forma mais fácil de fazer uma query, na qual não seja muito pesada e que consiga ler todas as tabelas com vários campos diferentes.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma é utilizar a cláusula `UNION` e juntar os resultados de pesquisa:

```
SELECT 'TABELA 1' AS origem
       t1.campo1,
       t1.campo2
  FROM tabela1 t1
 WHERE t1.campo1 like '%texto%'
    OR t1.campo2 like '%texto%'
UNION
SELECT 'TABELA 2' AS origem
       t2.campo1,
       t2.campo2
  FROM tabela2 t2
 WHERE t2.campo1 like '%texto%'
    OR t2.campo2 like '%texto%'
...
UNION
SELECT 'TABELA 10' AS origem
       t10.campo1,
       t10.campo2
  FROM tabela3 t10
 WHERE t10.campo1 like '%texto%'
    OR t10.campo2 like '%texto%'
```